# I'm curious how i would grab a char that is the smallest/biggest out of the rest in said string without using ARRAYS

Tags: java

I'm just having a hard time grasping this concept.

each char has a different ASCII value, so how do i grab the lowest value or the highest value?

and if i passed an empty string to my method for all of this `min()` would just get thrown an error or would it return a 0?

i wrote a test driver that should pass if my min method returns w as the minimum, which is just a stub method right now, character in that string.

```
    final String PASS = "Pass";
    final String FAIL = "Fail";

    L05A lab5 = new L05A();

    int testNum = 1;
    String tst = "";    // test empty string
    String result = FAIL;


    System.out.println("\nTesting min\n");


    tst = "";
    char ch  = lab5.min(tst);
    result = (ch == '!') ? PASS : FAIL;

    System.out.println(testNum + ": " + result);
    ++testNum;


    tst = "zyxw"; //would return w?
    ch  = lab5.min(tst);
    result = (ch == 'w') ? PASS : FAIL;

    System.out.println(testNum + ": " + result);
    ++testNum;
```

So how would i scan that string i pass to return the smallest char?

At first i thought i could use str.charAt(0); but silly me, that just returns the first index of the string, so i'm very confused! Any help would be great to develop this min method

I SHOULD SPECIFY THAT WE ARE NOT USING ANY FORM OF ARRAYS[] ON THIS ASSIGNMENT
UNFORTUNATELY.. :(

Comment: How would you find the smallest int in an array of ints?

Comment: Turn the string into a chararray. Iterate through it and compareTo the min char with the next char of the array for determining the min. The min initially in the first element.

Comment: I think arrays go beyond the scope of the assignment, we havent even talked about them yet. I'm not too sure :/ just in my beginner java course, i imagine something like if index[0] of the array is < 1 than its not the min?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

1. Convert the string to a `char` array using `String.toCharArray`
2. Convert the array to a `Collection<Character>`
3. Pass the collection to `Collections.min` and `max` from `java.util.Collections`

For example:

```
String test = "test";
List<Character> strArr = new ArrayList<Character>(test.length());
for (char c : test.toCharArray()) strArr.add(c);
System.out.println(Collections.min(strArr)); // prints "e"
```

**EDIT** Ok, so now you say you can't use `Arrays`, so you just do this instead:

```
String test = "test";
char[] chars = test.toCharArray();
char max = Character.MIN_VALUE;
char min = Character.MAX_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
  char c = chars[i];
  max = max > c ? max : c;
  min = min < c ? min : c;
}
System.out.println(min);
```

And, finally, if you can't use an array (like `char[]`) then you just drop the `toCharArray` call, and start the loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {
  char c = test.charAt(i);
```

Comment: We're not allowed to use Arrays :( any other advice?

Comment: @ErikVorcov. Well that was a key piece of information to leave out.

Comment: @ErikVorcov. Then you could try doing a simple comparison loop instead, as per my edit.

Comment: What is the char[] chars = test.toCharArray(); do? I see that you're looping through the index's of the string very interesting. Could you break this down a little bit for me?

Comment: @ErikVorcov. line 2 gets a char array from the string using the `toCharArray` method on `String`. After that you set the lowest possible `char` value to `max`, and for each `char c` in the array you test: if the character is more than `max` write it to `max`, otherwise write `max` to `max` (i.e. do nothing). The reverse is done for `min`

Comment: Would the toCharArray method thats called take the string "test" for example and put it into an array? i understand what we're doing i just would hate to get a bad grade for using arrays and going beyond the scope

Comment: @ErikVorcov. When you say you can't use `Arrays`, do you mean `java.util.Arrays`, or arrays of the form `char[]` - they are totally different?

Comment: I'm really sorry to cause confusion @AndyBrown i'm very new hah. When i say arrays, i really mean like in my CS1 class we literally havent used the word Arrays once yet this semester, so i imagine none of the sort.. how would you loop through `min(String str)` str without converting it to an Array?

Comment: @ErikVorcov. Use the `String.charAt` method. See my edit. Top tip: read [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for the class you are dealing with, you will quickly spot the method you want. You literally just search online for "java" and the classname, and you get the java docs for it at oracle.

Comment: If i wanted to seperate the Min and Max because i need to have two different methods could i just do the 'max()' by removing the `char max` and the `max = max > c ? max : c;` and rewriting the min method the same just replacing it with max? @AndyBrown

Comment: @ErikVorcov. I'm afraid SO is designed for one query per posted question. You should mark the best answer that helped you as accepted, and then ask a new question given your new knowledge and understanding of the problem, and the resulting new issue you face. Apart from anything else you will get much better help if you do it this way.

Comment: could i just do the `max()` in a seperate method by removing the char max and the `max = max > c ? max : c;` and rewriting the min method the same just replacing it with max? I tried doing this and was all my test cases Failed? @AndyBrown

Answer (score 1):

1. get char array out of string
2. iterate over it
3. define temp int variable assign to 0
4. compare ASCII of char to temp var and assign temp var to ascii if temp var is smaller/bigger(based on min max value you need from that function)
5. once the loop is over, you have what you want in that temp var

Answer (score 0):

I expect there is a utility class which will do this for you, but what you could do is call toCharArray on the string, iterate over the array it returns and look for the smallest char (char is effectively a number so comparisons like < > <= >= etc will work on it)

edit:

```
    String foo = "ksbvs";
    final char[] chars = foo.toCharArray();
    // create a variable to bung the smallest char in
    // iterate over the array chars
    // compare the current char to the smallest char you have seen so far, update if it's smaller
```

Comment: Would i be able to write a statement like If (the first index of the string > 'a') then go to the next index of the string and repeat but how would i define the first index of a string and then iterate through however many char's there are in it

Answer (score 0):

You should sort the array first:

```
Arrays.sort(arr);
```

Then your minimum value will be its first element:

```
int minimum = arr[0];
```

Do note that Arrays.sort does sorting [in-place and returns nothing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).

Comment: not allowed to use Arrays :( forgot to post in the title, very sorry

Comment: I'm sorry, I had no idea you were being lazy and trying to get your homework done for you

Comment: If that was the case i would be using other means to do this.. this website is for educational purposes and i was encouraged to use it. Theres a difference between giving someone code and showing them snippits and explaining it. ty

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestCharASCIIValue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String slogan = "Programming Java Makes me go nutts"; // The String under test
        int maxASCII = 0;   // As minimum value for a character in ASCII is 0.
        int minACSII = 255;   // As maximum value for a character in ASCII is 255
        int stringLength = slogan.length(); 
        for(int i =0; i < stringLength; i++) {
            int tempASCII = slogan.codePointAt(i);
            if(tempASCII > maxASCII)
                maxASCII = tempASCII;
            else if (tempASCII < minACSII)
                minACSII = tempASCII;
        }
        System.out.println("Max : " + maxASCII + " MIN : " + minACSII);
        char maxChar = (char)maxASCII;
        char minChar =  (char) minACSII;
        System.out.println("MaxChar : "+maxChar +"\t MinChar : " + minChar);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
Max : 118      MIN : 32

MaxChar : v    MinChar :  (blank space)
```

**EDIT :** As per your Query, If you want to test only for max or min valued char then you can use this.

```
public class TestCharASCIIValue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String slogan = "Programming Java Makes me go nutts";
        char maxChar = (char)getMaxChar(slogan);
        char minChar = (char)getMinChar(slogan);
        System.out.println("MaxChar : "+maxChar +"\t MinChar : " + minChar);
    }

    private static int getMaxChar(String testString) {
        int maxASCII = 0;
        int stringLength = testString.length();
        if(stringLength == 0) {
                 return -1;
        } 
        for(int i =0; i < stringLength; i++) {
            int tempASCII = testString.codePointAt(i);
            if(tempASCII > maxASCII)
                maxASCII = tempASCII;
        }
        return maxASCII;
    }

        private static int getMinChar(String testString) {
            int minASCII = 255;
            int stringLength = testString.length();
            if(stringLength == 0) {
                 return -1;
            }
            for(int i =0; i < stringLength; i++) {
                int tempASCII = testString.codePointAt(i);
                if(tempASCII < minASCII)
                    minASCII = tempASCII;
            }
            return minASCII;
        }
}
```

Comment: If i wanted it to only test for the min(because i have a seperate method for the max aswell :P) could i use the same thing minus the else if?

Comment: @ErikVorcov, Yes Definately, Just wait for my next Edit